# Nesting for loops to create plots with sets of unique parameters

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to figure out how to produce plots for sets of unique data.
Say I've got a bunch of data, and each data file is tagged with two properties - in this case there's dmax and rho. Say I have dmax = 1, 2, 3 and rho = 4, 5, 6. I want to create one plot for each unique pair of parameters, so I should have 9 plots total.

I have a code that works for dmax = 1, 2, 3 that doesn't separate by rho (because my old data only used one rho). It spits out, in this case, 3 histograms total:

```
uDmax = np.unique([job['Dmax'] for job in jobs])

for uD in uDmax:
   <<<a bunch of matplotlib stuff>>>
```

I've tried just about every combination of nesting for-loops and if-statements that I can think of, but I'm just not getting it right. I've tried using if/elif-statements for each rho, then for each dmax and v. versa, nesting for-statements, various combinations, and so on. I usually end up with one set of data printed over and over, in this case 9 times - even though my real data skips some parameters (e.g. I only used all 3 rhos with dmaxes = 1,3 but not 2 - so really there should only be 6 unique plots). That, or I get one plot total.

Sorry if this isn't the best way to ask this question - this is my first time posting here! Any help would be wonderful.

**EDIT**:

I'm now thinking that it might be how the histogram's set up, potentially in `cond = [job['Dmax']==uD and job['rho0']==r for job in jobs]`.

If I run it as-is, I get len(uDmax) # of copies of each urho - but I have no idea which combination it's picking to output. So I'm getting, per the example, 9 plots, but it's 3 plots copied 3 times each.

```
uDmax = np.unique([job['Dmax'] for job in jobs])
urho = np.unique([job['rho0'] for job in jobs])

#for uD in uDmax:
#    for ur in urho:
 

for r in urho:
    for ud in uDmax:
        cond = [job['Dmax']==uD and job['rho0']==r for job in jobs]

        xhist, xbins = np.histogram(np.array(all_disps)[cond,:,0], 100)
        yhist, ybins = np.histogram(np.array(all_disps)[cond,:,1], 100)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.scatter(xbins[1:], xhist, label=r'$\delta x$')
        ax.scatter(ybins[1:], yhist, label=r'$\delta y$')

        def gauss(x, A, sigma, x0):
            return A*np.exp(-((x-x0)/sigma)**2)

        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

        xpopt, xpconv = curve_fit(gauss, xbins[1:], xhist)
        ypopt, ypconv = curve_fit(gauss, ybins[1:], yhist)


        ax.plot(xbins[1:], gauss(xbins[1:],*xpopt))
        ax.plot(ybins[1:], gauss(ybins[1:],*ypopt))

        ax.legend(fontsize=20)
        ax.set_title(str(r) + str(ud))
        ax.set_ylabel('N observations', fontsize=16)
        ax.set_xlabel('displacement', fontsize=16)

        ax.axvline(0, ls='--', c=[0.5,0.5,0.5])
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by skipping some combinations; do you want a way to specify that in the code, so that you only get 6 results instead of 9? Also, it's generally a good idea to post the code you've tried, so we can help you troubleshoot it. That said, your core question is clear enough that I went ahead and posted something that should at least get you started. If you comment with clarification I'll edit it in response.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: In light of your edit, I'm replacing my previous answer.

Caveat: I'm not familiar with numpy, and I don't know what your `all_disps` variable is, so I may be missing some nuance since I don't really understand what the `xhist, xbins` assignment is doing. It looks, however, like your assignment of `cond` iterates through the list of jobs all over again for each iteration of the loop, which is inefficient even if you manage to get it working properly. `cond` can also end up being a list of zero, one, or more jobs, depending on how many match the selected `rho` and `dmax`—not sure if that's intentional or not.

Unless I'm mistaken, you're looking to make a plot of each `job`, except that you want to *skip* a `job` if you've already plotted a `job` with the same `rho` and `dmax`. This seems to suggest keeping a running list of value pairs you've already encountered, and skipping an iteration with `continue` when you realize you've already seen a pair before.

```py
jobs = [
    {'rho0': 4, 'Dmax': 1},
    {'rho0': 4, 'Dmax': 1}, # This one's a repeat, so we don't want to plot it.
    {'rho0': 4, 'Dmax': 2},
    
    {'rho0': 5, 'Dmax': 1},
    {'rho0': 5, 'Dmax': 2},
    
    {'rho0': 6, 'Dmax': 1},
    {'rho0': 6, 'Dmax': 3},
]
seen_values = set() # Could be a list instead, but a set is faster to check

for job in jobs:
    rho = job['rho0']
    dmax = job['Dmax']
    
    if (rho, dmax) in seen_values:
        # Stop this iteration of the loop and jump to the next iteration.
        continue
    
    # If we're still here, it means we have a rho/dmax pair not yet encountered.
    seen_values.add((rho, dmax))
    print(f'Plotting rho: {rho}, dmax: {dmax}')
    # [plotting stuff]
```

Output:

```
Plotting rho: 4, dmax: 1
Plotting rho: 4, dmax: 2
Plotting rho: 5, dmax: 1
Plotting rho: 5, dmax: 2
Plotting rho: 6, dmax: 1
Plotting rho: 6, dmax: 3
```

Comment: @aadam873 Did this edited/replaced answer help any? If not, my guess is you have an issue in the lines assigning histograms, and would recommend you edit your question to include `numpy` as a tag.